# Application Insights stops collecting traces after upgrade

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights, quarkus

For our Java application(Quarkus), in order to improve logging, we decided to upgrade our Application Insights Agent jar from 3.2.8 to 3.4.8. However, after the upgrade, we can query dependencies on the service but when we query the logs, it doesn't return anything. We tried it on other services but the result was the same. We also changed the self-diagnostic level to "Traces" but didn't see any errors.

Comment: [transforming to comment] @IbrahimD, can you please review your applicaitoninsight.log and applicationinsights.json? Or send them to appinsightsjavahelp@microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the logging was turned off in applicationinsights.json config:

```
"instrumentation": {
    "logging": {
      "level": "OFF"
    },
}
```

The problem is that this config was the same when we used the older version but clearly didn't have an effect. Once the level changed to `INFO` logging started to work as expected.

Comment: looks related to this fix: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/pull/2592, feel free to open future questions/issues directly in https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues